# Can't mock `willReturn` with Optional in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, option-type, mockito-kotlin

I have a method

```kotlin
fun getUser(userId: UserId): Optional<User?> = userRepository.findById(userId)
```

that returns an Optional in Java.
So I want to mock that method call in my Kotlin unit test.

This was my first guess...

```kotlin
given { mockedUserService.getUser(currentUser.userId) }.willReturn(Optional.of(currentUser))
```

... but the compiler says no

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Optional but Optional<User?>! was expected

So I started to make the `val currentUser: User?` just to make the compiler happy.

```kotlin
given { currentUser?.userId?.let { mockedUserService.getUser(it) }.willReturn(Optional.of(currentUser))
```

> Type mismatch: inferred type is Optional but Optional<User?>? was expected
>
> Type mismatch: inferred type is User? but TypeVariable(T) was expected

And now I am somewhat lost. How can I make the compiler happy?

Comment: can you please share the full signature of `UserService.getUser(userId: UserId)` including the return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to fix the test, but that is actually not the problem here. You should avoid `Optional` whenever possible in Kotlin. Java's type system has no way to distinguish nullable and non-nullable values. Kotlin does, so you should transform the `Optional<T>` as early as possible to `T?`.

You can easily fix your function like that:

```
fun getUser(userId: UserId): User? = userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(null)
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider this as an alternative. I am assuming you are using Java's type `Optional` and not your own implementation (doing more than I can see here).

The `Optional` came to Java to avoid a NPE and indicate an abscent of a type at runtime. But in Kotlin you do not really need an Optional, since you can explicitely define your type as nullable `T?`.

So you can either define it as:

```kotlin
fun getUser(userId: UserId): User?
```

or

```kotlin
fun getUser(userId: UserId): Optional<User> // not nullable!
```

Comment: Well you're right `Optional<User?> ` is a bit redundant as I am thinking about it

Comment: Let me know if this approach fixes your testing problem.

Comment: That's not an alternative. I guess that should be the chosen answer. Avoid Optional in Kotlin.

Answer (score 2):

You could try **willAnswer** instead of **willReturn**:

```
given { mockedUserService.getUser(currentUser.userId) }.willAnswer { Optional.of(currentUser) }
```

Comment: Okay, but why? What are the differences? Why this works while the former doesn't?

Comment: Usually you would use **willAnswer** if you need to compute the return value somehow. It does not enforce the type of the return value at compile time like **willReturn** does. If you would return a String in the example above, the code would still compile, but you would get a ClassCastException at runtime.
That being said, this should be considered a workaround.